# How get objects from one array with same properties of other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsset

For example:
I have two `NSMutableArray`. One `@[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. Other have objects like

```
@[
   @{@idObjectToSearch":1, @"name":@"aaaaa", @"surname": @"bbbbb"}, @{@idObjectToSearch":2, @"name":@"aaaaa", @"surname": @"ccccc"},
    ...
   @{@idObjectToSearch":100, @"name":@"aaaaa", @"surname": @"cccdcd"}
];
```

So how I could extract needed objects from second array more effective way?

Comment: What is the link between this two arrays, based on what you want to extract object from  second array ?

Comment: @Rajat I needed all objects by "idObjectToSearch"

Comment: Unless you want to load the objects from the second array into a dictionary keyed by the `idObjectToSearch` value (and this is what i would do) any technique you use will be a linear search of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `NSPredicate` with your second array.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idObjectToSearch IN %@", firstArray];
//In above predicate instead of passing `1` you need to pass object from first array that you want.

NSArray *filterArray = [secondArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

//Now access Array objects
if (filterArray.count > 0) {
     NSLog(@"%@",filterArray);
}
```

Comment: It's return only one object, but I need all 7, as in example. So I could to form a long predicate with OR, but I didn't think that this is good way for my case.

Comment: @Viktorianec then you need to use `IN` check the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
NSMutableArray * arrSorted = [NSMutableArray new];
for(int i=0;i<arr.count;i++) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idObjectToSearch == %@", firstArray[i]];
    NSUInteger index = [secondArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [predicate evaluateWithObject:obj];
    }];
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        [arrSorted addObject:[arrM objectAtIndex:index]];
    }
}
```

`arrSorted` will contain your sorted data